# Entity Ruler cannot recognize "Frankfurt am Main" as Geo-Political Entity (GPE)

Tags: python, spacy

I try to add a new rule in Named Entity Recognition so that Spacy will label the phrase "[Frankfurt am Main](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt)" as GPE.

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler")
patterns = [{"label": "ORG", "pattern": "MyCorp Inc."},{"label": "GPE", "pattern": "Frankfurt am Main"}]
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
doc = nlp("MyCorp Inc. is a company in Frankfurt am Main")
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
```

But Spacy still label the word "Frankfurt" as GPE instead of the whole phrase "Frankfurt am Main":

```
[('MyCorp Inc.', 'ORG'), ('Frankfurt', 'GPE')]
```

I want to know how I can adjust spacy so that it can label "Frankfurt am Main" as GPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `entity_ruler` before `ner` so that its entity spans have priority over the `ner` entities.

```py
nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler", before="ner")
```

See: https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler-usage